# Regex Search with delimiters in and Mysql

Tags: mysql, regex

I'm trying to convert a regex that works fine in PHP to MySQL.
MySQL does not allow negative look-ahead `(?!)` so I need a solution or a workaround

My DB column data is a string like this:

> title:The Book Title¬#¬description:The Book Description¬#¬Price:$10.57

The regex I can use in PHP would be

> (^|¬#¬)title:(((?!¬#¬).)*Book((?!¬#¬).)*)

but in MySQL I'm struggling. Anybody have any advice or suggestions

Comment: Can't you just split at `¬#¬`, then split at `:`?

Comment: As you've asked for _any_ advice, mine would be to normalize your data first. Having three different fields clumped together in one column looks bizarre.

Comment: how would you do that via a mysql query ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simple once I thought about splitting it like nhahtdh suggested.

```
select 
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTR(table.data, LOCATE('title:', table.data)+6), '¬#¬', 1) regexp '[[:<:]]Book[[:>:]]' AS hasResult
from 
  table;
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't have a way to apply a REGEX to col's content in SELECT clause.

You may use SUBSTRING function to extract your content in this case.

```
SELECT 
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(
        LEFT( content, LOCATE('?#?description', content)-1 ), 'title:', -1) AS title,
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(
        LEFT( content, LOCATE('?#?Price', content)-1 ), 'description:', -1) AS description,
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(
        RIGHT( content, LOCATE('?#?Price', content)-1 ), 'Price:', -1) AS price
FROM test_table
```

SQLFiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/04e83/1